# Move an already created rectangle in canvas

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to move an item in canvas by clicking and dragging the object. I am using `paperjs`. Here is my code:

I drawing a rectangle as follows:

```
 var rect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(100, 100), new  paper.Point(200, 250));
    rect.strokeColor = 'black';
    rect.fillColor = 'red';
    rect.strokeWidth = 5;
```

To move the rect, I am creating a `Tool` and attaching events to it.

```
onSelectShape(){
        const self = this;
        const hitOptions = {
          segments: true,
            stroke: true,
            fill: true,
      tolerance: 5
        };


        const toolSelect = new paper.Tool();
        toolSelect.activate();


        let segment, path;
        toolSelect.onMouseDown = function(event) {

            const hitResult = self.project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
      console.log(hitResult);
            if (!hitResult){
                return;
            }
            if (hitResult) {
                path = hitResult.item;
            }

        };

        toolSelect.onMouseMove = function(event) {
            self.project.activeLayer.selected = false;
            if(event.item){
                event.item.selected = true;
            }
        };

        toolSelect.onMouseDrag = function(event) {

            if (path) {

                path.position += event.delta;
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is the complete [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdl3wf) link. I am not sure why it is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

line 31 change

```
const self = this;
```

to

```
const self = paper.project;
```

line 69 change

```
path.position += event.delta;
```

to

```
path.position = path.position.add(event.delta);
```